# Display tooltips in javascript/HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have a HTML table with text box and a button
Initially text box is hidden and after press the button it will display.
This works perfectly.
What I need to do is dispaly a tooltip saying "Enter your name here" on the right side of the text box,
at the same time the text box appears.
(Not when the mouse over the text box. Need to display the tooltip when the text box appears)

Can anyone please help me to solve this problem?

This is my code so far.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function showRow(rowId) {
            document.getElementById(rowId).style.display = "";
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr id="r1">
            <td>
                <input type="button" id="click" name="click" value="click" onclick="showRow('r2');"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="r2" style="display: none;">
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="name" name="name"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
<html>
```

Comment: What about just a placeholder attribute? `<input type="text" placeholder="Enter your name here"/>`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the 'tooltip' to display at the same time, then simply add an element as a child of your `<td>` element.

From:

```
<tr id="r2" style="display: none;">
    <td><input type="text" id="name" name="name"></td>
</tr>
```

To:

```
<tr id="r2" style="display: none;">
    <td>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
        <label for="name">My Label</label>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Hopefully that should work. (I dunno if that's what you're asking)

Check this JSFiddle I just created:

https://jsfiddle.net/0mfk3tr3/

Comment: That is just a label you displayed along with text box. Op wants `tooltip` to be displayed on text box as soon as it appears.

Comment: But a tooltip that is always visible is just a label with some fancy positioning? Is it not. @Rohit416

Comment: It is, but then we should not call it a tooltip. Making text wrap in a label will just be fine.